# Icenium experience and recommendations

Tags: mobile

I have to develop a mobile application that is available on Android and iOS.

I do not have any experience with native development for Android or iOS, so I decided to go with some of the existing platforms like PhoneGap, Titanium or [Icenium](http://www.icenium.com/) (these platforms provide me with all necessary requirements).

I saw that Icenium requires an invitation code to go through the documentation.

What I want to ask: Has someone played with Icenium? Any recommendations about this cloud-based platform? What about performance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been working with Icenium and I can say that it is fun so far.  It is really just an IDE that allows you to use Cordova (PhoneGap) to build apps.  There are two IDEs -- one that is browser based and one that is a Windows desktop app.  The native desktop app is more featured and has a better User Experience.  There is some poetic justice there, if you are looking for it :)

So far, it is certainly young.  Support for things like PhoneGap plugins is non-existent so far.  I also can't seem to get the app working on a real device, but these are beta bugs and I expect them to be smoothed out.

Although the cloud-based approach is nice because I don't have to worry about using multiple IDEs, you lose a lot of freedom for how you want to develop.  For instance, I like using CoffeeScript and there is no support for building, compiling, creating new CS files, etc.  Possibly in the future?

Since it is really just an IDE for developing Cordova (PhoneGap) apps, it isn't a different platform from Cordova.  It just makes development a bit more streamlined.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm part of the Icenium team.

Thanks for the great write up Brian. Can you share more details about your problem running the app on a device over at our forums - http://icenium.com/community/forums?

Regarding your requests plugins are in the works and soon will hit the Icenium instance near you. We have some future plans about CoffeeScript support, but we want the community to drive us. You can vote for it here - https://feedback.telerik.com/Project/87/Feedback/Details/774-coffeescript-support

-sdobrev

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that from my personal experience , Icenium is slow. They market it as being html5 apps that work like native apps and this is just not the case. You can make it look like a native app and you can develop it with the native ideology as it were, letting the user experience it as if it were native, but its so slow.

Its also really odd how a microsoft technology based company ( that is telerik ) has basically removed itself from the microsoft stack with icenium. I am not saying that is bad , microsoft itself needs to do more to attract developers to its platform. Its just really odd because most of the telerik clients use the mircosoft stack , including , very importantly visual studio. Everyone knows VS they have custom plugins that suit their development style and now we must learn and use a new IDE that is so far , in my opinion not even close to the standards of anything. The one primary advantage is that you can deploy to a device.

Adding Phonegap or any other mobile based framework can be done in anything. It also does not provide support for microsoft devices at all. Which removes completely the whole cross platform environment that it seems this was supposed to be created for.

If you are not developing for microsoft , i guess its fine , but i dont see any other advantage other then it can deploy to the device for testing. If you have clients that work on the MS stack .. i would not recommend this at all. Just fire up VS and develop as you have before and just include those libraries in your file system.

Comment: I'm part of Icenium team as well. You would be glad to know that Icenium would introduce a Visual Studio plugin in its upcoming version next week. Windows phone support is also not far behind (beginning of 2014), but if you keep track of the phone market share, you would agree that ios and android were natural first choices.

Comment: Ill be looking very forward to it!! I really like a lot of the telerik products.

Comment: Icenium extension for Visual Studio (for now 2012 only) is already available, you can download it from here: http://cdn.icenium.com/live/vs/Icenium.vsix

Comment: Its ok i guess. The main functionality of syncing to a connected device through usb is not there, and the cloud build through qr takes so damn long. But geez like it so difficult to complain actually. The subscription is so damn cheap.

Comment: LiveSync for the Icenium VS extension is comming for the official version in mid November. Stay tuned!

Comment: LiveSync enabled!! This is epic. I take back my comment!